# Remove all XML Attributes with a Given Name

Tags: c#, xml, replace

I am editing a series of XML files, and I need to remove all attributes with the name "foo". This attribute appears in more than one type of element. An example snippet from the XML might be:

```
<bodymatter id="######">
  <level1 id="######">
    <pagenum page="#####" id="######" foo="######" />
    <h1 id="#####" foo="#####">Header</h1>
    <imggroup id="#######">
               .
               .
              etc.
```

The best solution I have uses Regex:

```
Regex regex = new Regex("foo=\"" + ".*?" + "\"", RegexOptions.Singleline);
content = regex.Replace(content, "");
```

I know built-in XML parsers could help, but ideally I want to make simple XML replacements/removals without having to deal with the baggage of an entire XML parser. 
Is Regex the best solution in this case?

**Edit**:

After some research in the XmlDocument class, here is one possible solution I came up with (to remove more than one attribute type stored in the array "ids"):

```
private void removeAttributesbyName(string[] ids)
{
    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    doc.Load(path);
    XmlNodeList xnlNodes = doc.GetElementsByTagName("*");
    foreach (XmlElement el in xnlNodes)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i <= ids.Length - 1; i++)
        {
            if (el.HasAttribute(ids[i]))
            {
                el.RemoveAttribute(ids[i]);
            }
            if (el.HasChildNodes)
            {
                foreach (XmlNode child in el.ChildNodes)
                {
                    if (child is XmlElement && (child as XmlElement).HasAttribute(ids[i]))
                    {
                        (child as XmlElement).RemoveAttribute(ids[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is as efficient as it possibly could be, but I've tested it and it seems to work fine.

Comment: Regex and XML don't mix.

Comment: RegeXml, not a pretty thing

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Do not use regex for XML manipulation. You can use Linq to XML:

```
XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
foreach (var node in xdoc.Descendants().Where(e => e.Attribute("foo")!=null))
{
    node.Attribute("foo").Remove();
}

string result = xdoc.ToString();
```

Comment: I figured Regex was not a good idea, but I was reluctant to go digging through all the method libraries for built-in XML parsers. Now I am looking into the XmlDocument class, however, and I may also make use of what you have here. Thanks!

Comment: Just to help out anyone like me who is a slow learner; I was getting error CS1061, saying I was missing a reference.  To be sure, you need using refs for  "System.Linq.Xml" and "System.Linq" for the above code to work.

Answer (score 2):

> Is Regex the best solution in this case?

No.

You'll want to use something that works on XML at the object level (as an `XmlElement`, for example) and not at the `string` level.

Answer (score 0):

I use the following to remove namespaces. This might also work in removing attributes from other nodes as well.

```
       FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open);

       StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(fs);

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.ReadXml(sr);
        ds.Namespace = "";

        string outXML = ds.GetXml();
        ds.Dispose();
        sr.Dispose();
        fs.Dispose();
```